# rake assets:precompile every time I edit CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

When I looked at the HTML source for my main page, the CSS that Rails was linking to was in `/stylesheets/application.css`. When I tried to click that link, I would get a 404 not found error from Passenger (Apache).

So what ended up working was setting `config.assets.compile = true` in my config file and running `rake assets:precompile`. This then changed the CSS link to something like `/assets/application-5310fa2adccd74453c084cf221eaeeef.css`, and this was something I could click on and could be found.

So now what I'm doing is every time I edit my CSS file, I run precompile. Is this the correct way to do things? Do I really have to call this every time I edit my CSS file? Is this the purpose of precompiling, to make sure my assets are able to be served by Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are running your application in production mode, it is advised to precompile the static assets to enhance the performance.

But if you want to skip it, you can use

**In config/environmets/production.rb**

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

After this, you don't need to precompile assets after any change in css but it can slow down the performance and speed of your page load.

Comment: I have this to true. When I change a property in my CSS file, it doesn't update the CSS file served by the browser. It still points to `/assets/application-5310fa2adccd74453c084cf221eaeeef.css`, which is an older precompiled version.

Comment: then restart your server and clean assets by running rake assets:clean

Comment: Ok now it seems that it is only concatenating my application.css file and ignoring all my other css files. What could this be?

Comment: Actually never mind had to delete the manifest file, and now it compiles all the css files.

Comment: it should include all css files if u have required those in application.css like this: /*= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/  require_tree will include all your css files in stylesheets directory.